# Is it possible to develop custom Ansible modules w/o Ansible source code?

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

According to [Ansible's developer's guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) the first thing to do is to check out the Ansible project. And from there add your own module in **ansible/modules/**, add supporting code into **ansible/module_utils**. Put your test code in **ansible/test/units/module/** and use the Ansible test utilities in **ansible/test/units/module/utils.py**.

The documentation is mute about how to distribute custom modules.

However, looking to the development method I think it's a safe assumption people are meant to maintain their own version of Ansible. After extending Ansible's source code, they have to rebuild the whole lot. From there they distribute this version of Ansible instead of the stock Ansible.

Personally, I think this is impractical:

- Source code management gets complex.
- There is no easy way to develop a custom module for a range of Ansible releases.
- Upgrading Ansible involves a complex source code merge.
- I'd rather not be involved in building from source a project like Ansible.
- Not to mention there is a real risk of breaking Ansible if I touch the wrong files.

I am aware of the method to make a Python package containing code in the **ansible/modules** namespace. Just pip install your package and voila, Ansible knows the module. This is exactly what I need.

However, developing separate code in the **ansible** namespace makes it impossible to import code from the installed Ansible library. And on top of that **ansible/test** has been removed from the Ansible library. There is no supporting testing code anymore.

Therefor, unless I'm wrong, the only way to develop a custom module independently from Ansible's source code is to hack my way in. I'd rather not do that.

Or is there a clean way to do this ?

Comment: You can distribute a module in a role that you can even reference on ansible galaxy: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#embedding-modules-and-plugins-in-roles. This is now also possible in collections: https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_collections.html